# MongoDB/Mongoid: is it possible to have an index on multiple fields with both unique and dropDups options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, duplicates, mongoid, unique-index

I have a model in a Rails 4.0.3 app which uses Mongoid 4 (master branch directly from GitHub), and I'm trying to ensure an index on multiple fields to be unique and to drop duplicates.

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document  

  field :a, type: Integer
  field :b, type: Integer

  index({a: 1, b: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true, name: 'unique_drop_dups_idx'})
```

But when I run the command to create indexes:

```
 rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

I get this error:

```
Problem:
  Invalid index specification on MyModel: {:a=>1, :b=>1}, {:unique=>true, :dropDups=>true, :name=>"unique_drop_dups_idx"}
Summary:
  Indexes in Mongoid are defined as a hash of field name and direction/2d pairs, with a hash for any additional options.
Resolution:
  Ensure that the index conforms to the correct syntax and has the correct options.
```

The index creation starts if I get rid of the `dropDups` option, even if it fails eventually because of the presence of duplicates.

Does the error message means that is not possible to create an index on multiple fields with this configuration (`unique` + `dropDups`)? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Interesting. Did you try dropping something like the name?

Comment: I'm no sure I get it. Are you suggesting to try the following on a different field type (e.g. String)?

Comment: No. I was interested if this worked `index({a: 1, b: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true })`

Comment: I gave it a try, unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: Well if the statement still fails by dropping that down to `index({a: 1, b: 1}, {unique: true})` I would scream bug. The almost exact example to that is on the manual page. At any rate. This smells like a bug.

Comment: Running `db.my_model.ensureIndex({a:1, b: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})` within the mongo console creates the index, properly removing the duplicates. It seems to be a `Mongoid` bug, I will report it.

Comment: Submit. This is a clear **fail**.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropDups` is not a valid index option for mongoid. You need to use `drop_dups` instead.

```
 index({a: 1, b: 1}, {unique: true, drop_dups: true, name: 'unique_drop_dups_idx'})
```

We try not to use camel case for options as we are on ruby land. You can see the mappings in here https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/indexable/specification.rb#L14.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Just watch out, your answer misspells the `drop_dups` keyword ;)